# Cannot create a new Spring web app in spring tool suite

Tags: spring, project

I trying to use spring mvc template, the wizard windows says 'requires downloading' but next button is disabled. I dont know what to do.

Comment: pasting code where you have problem is generally very helpful in getting responses

Comment: solved just input project's name. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just type in a project name in the field (on the top of the dialog). Then the Next button will be enabled.